# Как можно остановить цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал код, где ищу значение из массива: если хоть один из этих совподает, то должен видеть текст "Найден элемент", если не совпало, то "Не найдено". Получилось так:

```
x = [15, 65, 19]

for i in x:
    if(i == x):
        print('Найден элемент')
    else:
        print('Не найдено')
```

Когда элемент не найден, мне пишет трижды "Не найдено", пишу break - тогда следуюшего элемента не проверяет! Что не так с кодом?

Comment: совпадает с чем?

Comment: ну и как бы пройдесь с карандашом и листком бумаги по вашему алгоритму выполняя каждый шаг и поймете почему так происходит

Comment: `i == x` у Вас получается проверка равен ли один элемент списка всему списку? подобное сравнение всегда будет False

Comment: @Kers нет, не всегда

Comment: @Danis а можно пример что-то ничего не приходит в голову. Даже если элемент всего 1 число != список.

Comment: @Kers строка длинной в один элемент `"a"` либо список в котором он лежит сам `x = [];x.append(x)`

Comment: @Danis Спасибо за пример.  Про x даже не задумывался как-то, интересная особенность.. Со строками мне кажется чуть другая история.

Answer (score 4):

`x` - что ищем, `lst` - список с значениями

```
if x in lst:
    print('Найден элемент')
else:
    print('Не найдено')
```

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
x = [15, 65, 19]

for i in x:
    if(i == x):
        print('Найден элемент')
        break
else:
    print('Не найдено')
```

`else` выполниться только в том случае если цикл закончится сам, без вмешательство `break`

Comment: if i == x: не выполнится: там итерация по x )) и у вас else не на уровне if...

Comment: @Jack_oS else у меня стоит правильно

Comment: извините и спасибо за [for/else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html)! не сталкивался еще с такой конструкцией